# How to pass struct elements to asynchronous threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous

I am trying to launch a function threaded using `launch::async`. However, I noticed that this doesn't work when passing struct elements as parameter:
The code

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

struct example { int ten; };

void threadFunction(int number, std::string hi) { 
   printf("%s Your number is %d\n", hi.c_str(), number + 1);
}

int main() {
   example ex;
   ex.ten = 9;
   std::string someString = "Hi there!";
   std::vector< std::future< void > > threads(5);
   for (uint16_t s = 0; s < 5; s += 1) {
      threads[s] = async(std::launch::async,
                                   [ex.ten,
                                   someString] {
         threadFunction(ex.ten, someString);
      });
   }
}
```

gives the following errors:

```
file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
file.cpp:25:39: error: expected ‘,’ before ‘.’ token
                                    [ex.ten,
                                       ^
file.cpp:25:39: error: expected identifier before ‘.’ token
file.cpp:25:43: error: expected ‘]’ before ‘,’ token
                                    [ex.ten,
                                           ^
file.cpp: In lambda function:
file.cpp:25:43: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘,’ token
file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
file.cpp:26:46: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘]’ token
                                    someString] {
                                              ^
file.cpp:28:8: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       });
```

When replacing `ex.ten` with some other variable `ten` it does work.

So my questions are:
   1. Why does launch::async not work with struct elements?
   2. Is there a way to do it in a more elegant way than to make a variable for each element in the struct and pass those variables instead? (such as `int ten = ex.ten;` etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass single struct field that way into lambda in C++. The error you get is not connected to `std::launch` or communicating between threads. What you can do instead is:

C++11 - copy field into local variable and capture that variable:

```
auto ten = ex.ten;
threads[s] = async(std::launch::async,
                               [ten,
                               someString] {
     threadFunction(ten, someString);})
```

C++14 and later - initialize variable in capture list:

```
threads[s] = async(std::launch::async,
                               [ten = ex.ten,
                               someString] {threadFunction(ten, someString);})
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to capture a field in the struct in lambda. This is not possible, you can only capture the whole struct.

It has nothing to do with `std::launch`, it's a basic property of lambda closure.

In C++14, you can have captures with initializers, which might be what you want:

```
 auto lam = [ten = ex.ten]...
```

Comment: For completeness, since C++14, you can also effectively "rename" captures: these are "captures with initialisers", and the initialiser can be a struct member.

Comment: @GemTaylor that is true, I will add it for completness.